# Group items and rebuild list

Tags: jquery, html

I have a nested list which contains some string data. What i want is to iterate through the first list and check each "level-one" item and group together the ones that are same. Then i want to split the string inside by comma, so i can create sepparate items, to which is nest all items that were in list number 1 with same string value. I wanted to attempt it with iteration throught rach level-one and adding each unique to a array, and then somehow pair the level-two's that that one.

Starting list:

```
<ul>
    <li class="level-one">
        flowers,trees
        <ul>
            <li class="level-two">
                gardening
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="level-one">
        flowers,trees
        <ul>
            <li class="level-two">
                planting
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="level-one">
        orange,lemon
        <ul>
            <li class="level-two">
                fruit
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="level-one">
        orange,lemon
        <ul>
            <li class="level-two">
                citrus
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Expected result:

```
 <ul>
        <li class="level-one">
            flowers
            <ul>
                <li class="level-two">
                    gardening
                </li>
                <li class="level-two">
                    planting
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="level-one">
            trees
            <ul>
                <li class="level-two">
                    gardening
                </li>
                <li class="level-two">
                    planting
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="level-one">
            orange
            <ul>
                <li class="level-two">
                    fruit
                </li>
                <li class="level-two">
                    citrus
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="level-one">
            lemon
            <ul>
                <li class="level-two">
                    fruit
                </li>
                <li class="level-two">
                    citrus
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Corrected, even tho i think it was still clear enough what the result is supposed to be.

Comment: Sounds like you have a plan. So what have you tried and where'd you get stuck?

Comment: I kinda got stuck very early, i am not sure wether i should add full strings to an array first and then seapparate those by commas... am a bit stuck there already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easiest if you break it down step-by-step;

1. get all the `level-one` text and split them on the commas
2. ensure that the list we got has no duplicates
3. find the `level-two` list-items for each of those "categories"
4. duplicate them for later insertion (otherwise we just end up moving the `level-two` items around, and it's not clear if you want that or not)
5. insert everything

Note: I created an array `objs` that will contain the structure of what is needed to insert into the DOM at the end.

```js
$(function() {
  $("button#test").click(function() {
    let l1 = $("li.level-one");
    //get my list of first levels/
    let l1txt = $.map(l1, function(elem) {
      return $.trim($(elem).contents().first().text()).split(",");
    });
    //make the list unique
    l1txt = l1txt.filter(function(item, pos, self) {
      return self.indexOf(item) == pos;
    });
    //get the matching list-items
    let objs = $.map(l1txt, function(t) {
      return {
        level1: t,
        level2: findMatches(t)
      };
    });
    //console.log(l1txt);
    //console.log(objs);
    //findMatches("flowers");
    let $ul = $("<ul>"); //make the new ul to dump em in
    $ul.append($.map(objs, function(elem) {
      let $sub = $("<ul>").append(elem.level2); //these are the matched li's
      return $("<li class='level-one'>") //my new first item
        .append(elem.level1) //append the text 'category'
        .append($sub); //append that sub-list I just created
    })).insertBefore($(this)); //place this before my button I clicked.
  });
});
//locates the matching list-items for the "category"
function findMatches(level1) {
  //make sure we clone the list-items, so the old list can hang around untouched.
  return $(`li.level-one:contains("${level1}")  li.level-two`).clone().toArray();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id='test'>go</button>
<ul>
  <li class="level-one">
    flowers,trees
    <ul>
      <li class="level-two">
        gardening
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level-one">
    flowers,trees
    <ul>
      <li class="level-two">
        planting
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level-one">
    orange,lemon
    <ul>
      <li class="level-two">
        fruit
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="level-one">
    orange,lemon
    <ul>
      <li class="level-two">
        citrus
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Great, marked it as solution. i was thinking in solving it piece by piece but i choked and splicing them up and grouping them together.